# json.load() not returning anything

Tags: json, python-requests

Please assist below, I'm trying to grep Json data from a weather API; but when I call `json.load()` it's not returning anything:

```
def get_weather_from_api(location_id):
    api_key = ''
    url = f'http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/{location_id}?apikey={api_key}&language=en-us&details=false'

    response = requests.get(url)

    data = json.load(response.text)
    print(data)
```

Comment: what's the `response.status`? you can simply get `json` data as: `data=response.json()`

Comment: Try json.loads(response.text). Response.text usually is a string.

Comment: Thanks @Prateek Dewan, that worked; so load() expect an object not a string ?

Comment: Correct. load() is for objects, loads() is for strings.